# no implicit conversion of String into Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have the same action for all intents and purposes being executed. Yet one work and the other does not.

DB setup

```
add_column :cards, :score, :integer, :default => 0
add_column :cards, :comments, :integer, :default => 0

=> Card(id: integer, user_id: integer, event: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, score: integer, comments: integer)
```

The vote controller (this one works)

```
  def create
@vote = Vote.where(:card_id => params[:vote][:card_id], :user_id => current_user.id).first
if @vote
  @vote.up = params[:vote][:up]
  @vote.save
  @card = Card.find(params[:vote][:card_id])
  if @vote.up == true
    @card.score += 2
  else
    @card.score -= 2
  end
  @card.save
else
  @vote = Vote.new
  @vote.card_id = params[:vote][:card_id]
  @vote.user = current_user
  @vote.up = params[:vote][:up]
  @vote.save
  @card = Card.find(params[:vote][:card_id])
  if @vote.up == true
    @card.score += 1
  else
    @card.score -= 1
  end
  @card.save
end
redirect_to :back
end
```

comments controller (does not work) i get "no implicit conversion of Fixnum into Array"

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new
  @comment.message = params[:comment][:message]
  @comment.card_id = params[:comment][:card_id]
  @comment.user = current_user
  @comment.save
  @card = Card.find(params[:comment][:card_id])
  @card.comments += 1
  @card.save
  redirect_to :back
end
```

What am I missing here? Thank you all for your help in advance.

Ian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you also have an association between Cards and Comments, eg. `Card has_many :comments`. Your `@card.comments` method is now ambiguous - are you referring to the association or the value of the integer? Rails is assuming the association, but you wanted the integer.

For something like this, I suggest looking into **counter caches**: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference (section 4.1.2.3). This involves adding a `comments_count` field to your Card model, and `counter_cache: true` to the association from Comments to Cards. Rails will then maintain the count for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

@sevenseacat That did it. I posted the question before bed, and thought of exactly that when I was trying to fall asleep. I figured it could not be that. Thank you for confirming my thoughts and getting me to try it. I'm looking into the counter caches thank you for the point in a a better direction.

Ian